# Project Options in Qeditor of MASM32 isn't working

Tags: assembly, masm32

I Have Masm32 and I am using Qeditor. None of the options in Porject menu work. As an example if I click "Build All" nothing happens (no window, no files are build in the file directory, nothing happens).

I have c:\masm32\bin on my path so thats not the problem.

Comment: try using radasm, it's a much better choice.

Comment: I downloaded RadAsm but it only shows option for html files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too use MASM32 and, for a while, used Qeditor. I had the same problem as you, but overcame it by writing my own batch file for assembling projects. Eventually I switched to Notepad++ for writing code and eliminated Qeditor completely. Here's the batch file I wrote:

```
@if not exist %1.rc goto NoResource

  rc /foRes.res %1.rc
  cvtres /machine:ix86 /out:Res.obj Res.res
  del Res.res
  @if errorlevel 1 pause

  ml /c /coff /Fo%1.obj %1
  @if errorlevel 1 pause
  link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS %1.obj res.obj
  @if errorlevel 1 pause
  del %1.obj
  del res.obj

@goto Exit

:NoResource
  ml /c /coff /Fo%1.obj %1
  @if errorlevel 1 pause
  link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS %1.obj
  @if errorlevel 1 pause
  del %1.obj

:Exit
```

For my projects I'll have an assembly file `Project.asm` for example. If I need a resource file I will name it `Project.asm.rc`. When I want to assemble my project I will right click and "Open With" my batch file. It takes care of the rest.

Also, make sure your source files are located on the C: drive somewhere. This will make things much easier to work with.