# Where to start learning assembly - IDE, examples

Tags: assembly, ide, x86, masm

I have a solid knowledge of C#, I can use C quite well, and I am learning C++. I really would like to learn x86 assembly language for Windows, perhaps MASM, but I don't know where to start.
The first thing is the IDE. If at all possible I would like a syntax-highlighting, compiling, linking IDE, as I hate using command-line tools. I do have a nice enough editor, so just a compiler and linker GUI would also be fine. Does anybody have any recommendations?
I also am going to need some good tutorials on assembly, so if anyone knows of a good assembly intro, please post a link.

Comment: A number of existing questions cover this in detail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assembly tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906769/assembly-tutorial)

Comment: I did find some similar questions, but none that answered my questions. They were all "I recommend X assembler" or "John Doe has a good tutorial here" kind of thing. I would first like to find an IDE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of assemblers you can use [MASM](http://www.masm32.com/), [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/), ObjASM, [YASM](http://yasm.tortall.net/), [HLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Level_Assembly), and [TASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Assembler) among them. Personally, I use MASM because it does everything I need and the macros allow you to transition from C style code to MASM pretty easily.

As stated earlier, [Iczelion's Page](http://win32assembly.online.fr/) is an excellent resource. If you want a group dedicated to Windows assembly programming try the [ASM Community Message Board](http://www.asmcommunity.net/board/index.php). Despite its detractors, I also believe that [Kip R. Irvine's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013602212X) is one of the best out there covering windows development in MASM.

For syntax highlighting, I would suggest [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). For assembling, you can use the batch file I posted in this question: [Project Options in Qeditor of MASM32 isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349333/project-options-in-qeditor-of-masm32-isnt-working/6426138#6426138)

Assembly programming is a lot of fun. Ask lots of questions and good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I know of some books that are good to learn from. I am not sure of online tutorials. Some of the material you will find is a little outdated just be cautious.

- [http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Assembly-Language-Computer-Architecture/dp/0763772232/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1312331523&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0763772232)

Answer (score 1):

[Iczelion's Page](http://win32assembly.online.fr/) is almost all you need for Win32Asm programming. For an introduction in assembly look at [Randy Hyde's Page](http://homepage.mac.com/randyhyde/webster.cs.ucr.edu/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already familiar with c# then you should be comfortable with the Visual Studio 2010 IDE. My blog describes how to configure VS 2010 for MASM32 programming with libraries from MASM32.com. [scriptbucket.wordpress.com](http://scriptbucket.wordpress.com)

Answer (score 0):

I started by learning MIPS in my university so switching to x86 is not that hard but it requires a lot of study.
I suggest to you to buy or look for a solid and big book of x86 asm that contains even all the math basics required (logic gates, boolean algebra, numeric encoding, floating point etc.)
As ide i suggest to you to use SASM or visual masm, even visual studio can be adapted as a masm ide.

Comment: You really don't need any IDE to learn assembly language. You need an assembler (like [GNU as](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/), [nasm](https://www.nasm.us/), ...) and a good [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) such as [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or [vim](http://vim.org/) (or just [notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Notepad) on Windows...). If you improve your answer to avoid (confusingly) mentionning [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s, I would upvote you